# addOnBackStackChangedListener is not triggering in my android fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am new to android development and I am using `Fragment` with the `addOnBackStackChangedListener` to track my back stack change but it is not listening. Here is my complete code, every button works. Just it does not capture the back stack change event

```
package com.practice.personal.fragdemo;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentA fa;
    FragmentB fb;
    FragmentManager mgr;
    FragmentTransaction tx;
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mgr=getFragmentManager();
        txt=findViewById(R.id.message);
        mgr.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                FragmentManager.BackStackEntry entry;
                int c= mgr.getBackStackEntryCount();
                for(int i=c-1;i>c;i--){
                    entry=mgr.getBackStackEntryAt(i);
                    Log.d("ABD",txt.getText()+entry.getName()+"\n");
                    txt.setText(txt.getText()+entry.getName()+"\n");
                }
            }
        });


    }
    public void addA(View view){
        fa = new FragmentA();
        tx=mgr.beginTransaction();
        tx.add(R.id.group, fa,"A");
        tx.addToBackStack("A");
        tx.commit();

    }
    public void removeA(View view){
        fa = (FragmentA) mgr.findFragmentByTag("A");
        if(fa!=null) {
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.remove(fa);
            tx.addToBackStack("RA");
            tx.commit();
        }

    }
    public void replaceAB(View view){
        fb = new FragmentB();
        if(fb!=null) {
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.group, fb, "B");
            tx.addToBackStack("RPA");
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
    public void addB(View view){
        fb = new FragmentB();
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.add(R.id.group, fb, "B");
            tx.addToBackStack("B");
            tx.commit();
    }
    public void removeB(View view){
        fb = (FragmentB) mgr.findFragmentByTag("B");
        if(fb!=null) {
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.remove(fb);
            tx.addToBackStack("RB");
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
    public void replaceBA(View view){
        fa = new FragmentA();
        if(fa!=null) {
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.group, fa, "A");
            tx.addToBackStack("RPB");
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
    public void attachA(View view){
        fa = (FragmentA) mgr.findFragmentByTag("A");
        if(fa!=null) {
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.attach(fa);
            tx.addToBackStack("AA");
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
    public void detachA(View view){
        fa  = (FragmentA) mgr.findFragmentByTag("A");
        if(fa!=null) {
            tx = mgr.beginTransaction();
            tx.detach(fa);
            tx.addToBackStack("DA");
            tx.commit();
        }
    }
    public void back(View view){
        mgr.popBackStack();
    }
    public void pop(View view){

    }
}
```

I am using **Android Studio 3.0.1**. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `AppCompatActivity` ,so you need using the 
 `getSupportFragmentManager()` not the `getFragmentManager()`, see the doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: I tried the getSupportFragmentManager() and changed the FragmentManager, FragmentTransaction my Fragments to android.support.v4.app package objects instead of android.app package but still it is not capturing the event.

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; and replace all  getFragmentManager() with   getSupportFragmentManager()

Answer (score 3):

addOnBackStackChangedListener is used for the apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0. When running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used but it does not try to switch to the framework's implementation and hence it will not be invoked.

Comment: so what is the replacement ?